# Make maven output show progressed sub-modules only

Tags: maven, logging

I am working with an automatic build script in maven 3.x. The parent project contains of more than 60 modules. The compilation is done in a shell script simplified this way:

`for each module:
  cd module
  mvn clean install > compile.$module.log
  echo "Compiled $module"`

I like to see a list of compiled modules in order to see the progress or the build. I like to have a big maven command and avoid the manual for loop. I hope to speed up the build this way, since splitting the parent project into more independent modules is not a short time option, yet.

The --quiet flag might be enough already. Alternatively a user defined logging implementation would be fine as well, as described in the manual (https://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html)

The questions are:

- What is the prefered way to modify maven log output?
- Does anyone already know a ready-to-use plugin for my purpose?

Thanks

Comment: I recommend to use maven 3.5.4 there is an indicator contained...

Comment: The question is how you think about to speed up the build? About which time are we talking about? How long do your tests take ? Are you running parallel build? Are you running on SSD based machine? Do you use a CI solution like Jenkins?

Comment: Hi, there are about 5500 tests running in 3 minutes. The total build time in the loop above is 20 minutes. But thanks for the hint with the SSD. The CI server was rebuild 6 month ago, but I have no influence on the disks used. Maybe it is worth to measure disk i/o as well and compare it to my workstation. Locally the build is 10 minutes only.

Comment: If you local machine is faster than your build server than there is something wrong...apart from that 20 minutes is a long time...how many lines of code do you have? Have you tried to use parallel build?

Comment: Nearly 400k lines of code in 5000 classes. I did not use parallel build on CI yet, because I wanted to see the progress. I will try that and check if seeing progress is really that important.

Comment: This is a small project. I have a project which contains 1.5 million lines of code 800+ modules and builds in 6 minutes with parallel build etc. including 7500+ unit tests...

Comment: Is there a good reason why you don't run the build as a multi module build by Maven instead of running each module separately ?